# Get ID from URL and send it to PHP via Ajax

Tags: php, ajax

So I have a page `index.php?packageID=153`. That page has a form which when submitted is sent to PHP via Ajax call

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
 $(document).on('submit', '#form_name', function()
 {

  var data = $(this).serialize();


  $.ajax({

  type : 'POST',
  url  : 'phpfile.php',
  data : data,
  success :  function(data) {
                $('.result-modal').html(data);

            },
            error: function (request, status, error) {
                alert(error.responseText);
                //or console.log(request.responseText), or status or error;
            }
  });
  return false;
 });

});
</script>
```

I want to get that ID from the URL. I usually just do `$_GET['PackageID']` (in my PHP file) to get the ID from the URL when I'm not using Ajax, but it doesn't work with ajax (from what I'm experiencing). How do I get That ID in my PHP file?

Comment: change type : 'POST' to type : 'GET'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possibilites:

1. You insert the PackageID as a GET parameter into the url:

   ```
   url   : 'phpfile.php?PackageId=<?php echo $_GET['PackageID']; ?>',
   ```
2. You insert the parameter into the JavaScript data object like:

   ```
   var data = $(this).serialize();
   data.PackageId = <?php echo $_GET['PackageId']; ?>;

   $.ajax({
   [...]
   ```

However you do it, at some point you have to output text from PHP inside your JavaScript code.

Answer (score 0):

It's a PHP file so you can still use PHP. Add something like this at the top of the file.

```
<?php
echo '<script>';
echo "var id = $_GET['packageID']";
echo '</script>';
?>
```